# How to configure CI/CD Pipeline from BitBucket to Google Cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

We have a NodeJS application which we have deployed on Google Cloud App Engine. The source code is in Bitbucket. What is the best way to configure CI/Cd deployment? We want to deploy code from bitbucket to Google Cloud App Engine as code commit after performing test cases.

We want to know what to put in the configuration file in Bitbucket to set up with Google Cloud App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Build Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds) to automatically deploy an application stored in Bitbucket to App Engine when there is a new commit. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories), You can find a Quickstart for Automating App Engine Deployments with Cloud Build which the build gets triggered by a commit in Cloud Source Repositories and can be implemented on Bitbucket similarly.

- Note that, currently Build Triggers is in Beta and not intended for real-time usage in critical applications.